# Как обращаться к методам/переменным класса из класса, находящегося внутри?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, я хочу в классе Chindren обратиться к переменным класса, в котором находится Chindren.

Как я могу это сделать?

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 3;
    
    this.Chindren = class {
      constructor() {
        // this.b = Parend.a; // Не работает
        this.b = this.a;
        console.log(this.b);
      }
    }
  }
}

let parent = new Parent();
let children = new parent.Chindren();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    var _this = this;
    this.a = 3;
    
    this.Chindren = class {
      constructor() {
        // this.b = Parend.a; // Не работает
        this.b = _this.a;
        console.log(this.b);
      }
    }
  }
}

let parent = new Parent();
let children = new parent.Chindren();
```